# Firebase: Filtering nested queries is not working

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, geofire

I'm trying to do the SQL equivalent of a join query on Firebase, except that I'd like it to join only if the key `privacy` is equal to `public`.

The code below is not returning me the result. If I remove `child(key)` then it works fine, but it then won't be join. I'd really like some help with this.

```
circleQuery?.observe(.keyEntered, with: { (key: String!, location: CLLocation!) in

    self.locationRef.child(key).queryOrdered(byChild: "privacy").queryEqual(toValue : "public").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (locationSnapshot) in
        if !locationSnapshot.exists() { return }

        // returns no results
    }) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

})
```

Comment: you want to query in FirebaseDb and get result ?

Comment: Yes. As far as I understand, to perform the SQL equivalent of a join statement, I should set the keys of both tables to be equivalent, which I have done. What is different here is that I want to make the second query conditional, i.e. if privacy is set to public. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

to post and get result on base of query in firebase use following method

```
   let databaseReff = Database.database().reference().child("your parent node in which query will be searched and compared")

                databaseReff.queryOrdered(byChild: "fromId // parameter whose value will be checked").queryEqual(toValue: self.requiredID //Parameter which will be compared).observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
                    if snapshot.exists(){

                        print(snapshot.value!) //print full snapshot
                        if let snapDict:[String:AnyObject] = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] {

                            let dictKeys = [String](snapDict.keys)
                            print(dictKeys) //print all the nodes that will satisfy your query

                        }

                    }


                })
```

Comment: Right, but I'm performing two nested queries, and the second query is dependent on the key of the first. Oh and the second query is not an array, but is just one element.

Comment: yes you can do that too but according to it will be time consuming as you will hit the server again and again so its better to get snapshot on basis of one query and after that use that snapshot in a [string: anyobject] dict and sort it as per requirement it will load your data fast than first approach

Comment: I had usd query inside query earlier but I used my second approach to sort the data from one query. hope it helps

Comment: in case if you require query inside query I can post code for that after I test its working ?

Comment: That would be really helpful. TBH I'm a little ambivalent about combining the two models. I've read that it's good practice in SQL to keep the nesting to a minimum as it will load less data into memory per query.